# ¿Cómo interpretan "es muy psicólogo"?

Tags: expresiones

En [ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/494606/how-would-you-say-es-muy-psic%C3%B3logo/494613#494613) se planteó una pregunta interesante, en cuya respuesta participé: el caso de sustantivos "adjetivados" por el adverbio "muy" en la lengua coloquial (no me parece que el tema haya sido tratado en este sitio).

Existe un uso sarcástico de la construcción, como cuando se dice:

> Por **muy doctor** que sea, no tiene derecho a faltar el respeto a los demás.
>
> Será **muy ingeniero**, pero no sabe redactar un informe.

Mi pregunta es: ¿Cuál es su percepción sobre la oración "Es muy psicólogo"? ¿Es una oración para realzar la actitud psicológica de alguien? ¿O es una oración destinada a indicar que la persona en cuestión no es un psicólogo cualquiera, uno del montón, sino uno muy bueno o muy especial?

Comment: Me da la idea de que a esta persona le gusta analizar psicológicamente el carácter de otras personas.  Tendría que ver el contexto para saber si es una crítica o más bien una observación neutra.  Me imagino que se podría decir de cualquier persona de índole analítico, sin importar si estudió la psicología formalmente o no.

Answer (score 8):

Depende del contexto, pero mi interpretación es que la persona en cuestión, tenga o no un título en psicología, se comporta en demasía como tal, fuera del ámbito de la práctica psicológica.
Por ejemplo, analizando a sus pares, o utilizando léxico propio de la psicología.

Answer (score 3):

En mi opinión también depende mucho del contexto, pero yo asocio la expresión 'es muy psicólogo', como 'tiene mucha psicología' en relación a alguien con mucha comprensión de los demás, mucha profundidad en el análisis del comportamiento de la gente, incluso mucha intuición. En fin, yo lo relaciono normalmente con algo positivo, con un halago, así lo utilizo yo y lo oigo a menudo. Sin embargo. como comentáis, está claro que el contexto puede darle a la frase un tono decididamente sarcástico.