ser muy «sustantivo»
I have some related questions about "what is the meaning of "ser muy «sustantivo»"
See these questions for context:
¿Cómo interpretan "es muy psicólogo"?
and
https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/494606/how-would-you-say-es-muy-psic%C3%B3logo/494613#494613

For any typical usage of any sentence whatsoever, we can guess the probability of it being "sarcastic" or "a joke" are... certainly less than 10%.   In your opinion, is "ser muy «sustantivo»" more likely than average to be  "sarcastic" or "a joke"?  By the way, if we say "He's a real psychologist", in English that is absolutely mild sarcasm.   It's a joke at the expense of that person.  Does this also apply to the Spanish phrase. (or not).

Would you categorize the expression "ser muy «sustantivo»" as "slang"? As "proscribed"? As universally understood?

Could you rewrite "fulanito es muy psicólogo" with another combination of words,  a few more words, omitting "muy", and still capture the meaning?    Either in Spanish or English.


For example, is this right or wrong:
"That guy is quite perceptive when it comes to psychology."
Comparing that to the one with "muy"... Is it accurate/correct? or flawed? in what ways.

https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/29211/c%c3%b3mo-interpretan-es-muy-psic%c3%b3logo

Your point #1 is going to depend on context.  My wife is a psychologist, so I can say that "she's a real psychologist" with or without sarcasm depending on the context of how I use it.

Ok yes, it depends on context: when you say it about someone who is not officially a psychologist.

The question revolves around the possibility of using a noun after an adverb. In grammar, adverbs typically modify verbs, adjectives, or other adverbs.
My view is that, when used instead of adjectives, nouns modified by adverbs sound more colloquial.
"analista" can be a noun (analyst) or an adjective (analytical), and "preguntón" is mostly an adjective.
If we say that somebody is "muy hombre" or "muy mujer," it sounds a bit stronger and more colloquial than saying "muy masculino" or "muy femenina."
Describing people in those terms, that is, by adding an adverb to a noun, is not a literary usage, and tends to be more conversational than using an adjective proper.
Other similar uses can be:

Es bastante hombre.
Es bien hombre.
Es demasiada mujer.
Es re mujer.

The feminine gender of "demasiada" shows that, despite its adjectival use, "mujer" continues to be a noun.

Para mi no es ni ofensivo, ni peyorativo, ni sarcástico, ni una broma; es simplemente un comentario acerca de la personalidad de otra persona. Lo que intenta decir es que es muy perceptivo y analista de las personalidad de los demás.
De aquí deriva una variante alternativa:

es muy analista


if we say "He's a real psychologist", in English that is absolutely mild sarcasm. It's a joke at the expense of that person.

En Español NO lo es.
By the way, a mi personalmente me han dicho cosas mucho peores que "sicólogo" y en ningún caso resultó ofensivo. Pensando en palabras que pueden llegar a resultar ofensivas, tampoco lo son en un contexto de conversación o descripción. Por ejemplo:

es una tiquismiquis (picky)

por intentar encontrar una palabra que roce el límite de lo correcto, tampoco resulta ofensivo. Es simplemente la percepción de una persona respecto a otra.
El idioma Español es mucho más permisivo que el Inglés respecto a definiciones de personas. El Inglés por lo general suele ser más cauto.
Edit after the comment
Por dejarlo más claro: un "sicólogo" es un profesional que se dedica a la profesión de la sicología. Decirle a una persona que es un "sicólogo" jamás puede ser un sarcasmo. Es como decirle a alguien: tu eres muy farmacéutico o tu eres muy albañil.
A no ser que en una región en particular o una persona en particular tenga como prejuicio utilizar un término asociado a una profesión con cierta displicencia.
Creo que aquí se está tratando otro tema que nada tiene que ver con el idioma Español, sino más bien con los prejuicios que tenga cada uno o los respectivos a cada región. Yo jamás he sentido peyorativo que alguien se dirija a mi o me describa con mi profesión.
A no ser que se intente rebajar el escalafón. Por ejemplo decirle a un arquitecto "albañil" o a un diseñador "dibujante". Pero esto no es por el sustantivo en sí, sino por la definición y lo que abarca. El único "sarcasmo" que se me ocurre con el ejemplo de la pregunta es decirle "sicólogo" a un "siquiatra" sabiendo que son dos profesiones diferentes y que suelen confundirse.

is not something an educated person would say

No creo sea el caso. Insisto, me suena mucho a prejuicios o preconceptos.
Te sentirías ofendido si te digo:

eres muy preguntón

por participar en SpanishSE?

Thanks. Would you categorize the expression as "slang"? As "proscribed"? As universally understood?  From earlier comments, someone wrote, it "doesn't sound like very good Spanish" and "is not something an educated person would say."? Or maybe there are regional, dialect, differences.

Answer updated.–

@Sam By the way, after reading all the answers and comments in EnglishSE, it is a big mix of Spanish language and prejudices, and I don't think the latter are applicable globally to all the Spanish-speaking people.

I appreciate the answer, you have gone even more in detail about "sarcasm".and "prejudice". My question in the comments though, is almost another separate topic, another question.  Is "muy sustantivo" linguistically slang, is it proper literary Spanish.

It's Spanish, is not a slang
